# Count occurences of words in file

Tags: python, file, dictionary

I want to count the occurence of each word in a file using a dictionary (all words contained in the file are in lower-case and the file does not contain any punctuation).

I want to optimize my code because I am aware that the list takes unnecessary time.

```
def create_dictionary(filename):
    d = {}
    flat_list = []
    with open(filename,"r") as fin:
        for line in fin:
            for word in line.split():
                flat_list.append(word)
        for i in flat_list:
            if d.get(i,0) == 0:
                d[i] = 1
            else :
                d[i] +=1

        return d
```

For example, a file containing :

```
i go to the market to buy some things to 
eat and drink because i want 
to eat and drink
```

should return:

```
{'i': 2, 'go': 1, 'to': 4, 'the': 1, 'market': 1, 'buy': 1, 'some': 1, 'things': 1, 'eat': 2, 'and': 2, 'drink': 2, 'because': 1, 'want': 1}
```

What can I improve?

Comment: [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html?highlight=counter#collections.Counter) is great for that kind of thing.

Answer (score 1):

Just use `collections.Counter`:

```
with open(filename,"r") as fin:
    print(Counter(fin.read().split()))
```